# 3 latest record show into columns in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have LABTEST table  with code, values and test date. Now I have test values

```
TEST_NAME     TEST_VALUE    TEST_DATE
BP            100/60        01-01-2017
BP            100/50        02-01-2017
BP            80/60         03-01-2017
BP            70/60         04-01-2017
CBC           200           01-01-2017
```

I want 3 latest values column-wise. Want result look like below:

```
TEST_NAME     VALUE-1    VALUE-2   VALUE-3    
BP            80/60      100/50    100/60   
CBC           200        NULL      NULL
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Why are you writing in caps?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT TEST_NAME , TEST_VALUE , ColName
FROM 
    (
    SELECT *
            , 'Value-' + CAST( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TEST_NAME 
                                ORDER BY TEST_DATE DESC) AS VARCHAR(10)) ColName
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TEST_NAME 
                                ORDER BY TEST_DATE DESC) RN
    FROM YourTableName  
    ) x
WHERE rn <= 3
)
SELECT *
FROM X
       PIVOT ( MAX(TEST_VALUE)
               FOR ColName
               IN ([Value-1] , [Value-2] , [Value-3])
             )p
```